# Transforming a 2D array to 1D array to create Data Frame

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have three 2D np.array that mathematically are [8:1550] matrices, and I want to express them into 1D np.array of 12400 numbers (8 x 1550 = 12400...) so that I could create a DataFrame later with this code:

```
Exported_Data = pd.DataFrame({"UD": UD_Data, "NS": NS_Data, "EW": EW_Data})
Exported_Data.to_csv("EXCEL.csv")
```

To put a simpler example, if I have this:

```
A = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
              [4, 5, 6],
              [7, 8, 9]])
```

And I want to obtain this from that:

```
B = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest use `reshape`. It most likely creates a view and is more efficient whereas `np.flatten` creates a copy:

```
B = A.reshape(-1)
```

`-1` implicitly takes care of required dimension size.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `A.flatten()` to convert a 2D array to a 1D array.

Comment: So, flatten is exclusive for np.array isn't? It worked. I could've also used "reshape"?

Comment: I believe there are a few possible methods: `flatten`, `reshape`, `unravel`. From what I understand, `reshape` is the most flexible, being able to reshape between any dimensions, whereas `flatten` specifically reshapes into 1D (column or row vector). For your use case, `flatten` is sufficient, but in cases where you may require to switch between 3D-2D or 2D-3D, you'd need to use `reshape`.